# Image added in table's row takes up more row space that intended

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx

I was adding some images into the table with labels on the side, but the images are pushing the labels quite far away and hence distorting the overall layout.

The images are 640x640 in resolution.

The layout: [image]

I tried playing around with cell functions and tried padding the different rows and columns (kind of worked however this is not what I'm going for as it displaces the whole of the table's components) and I have read the table documentation in GitHub [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table), however I'm still stuck with the same issue.

**Here is the table layout code** (table initialised in class constructor)

```java
        int[] values;
        ArrayList<Label> labels = new ArrayList<>();
        //just setting up labels with according values, not really important
        if (label.getText().toString().contains("Conjurer")) values = new int[]{200, 9, 10, 15, 15};

        else if (label.getText().toString().contains("Monk")) values = new int[]{300, 14, 15, 11, 8};

        else values = new int[]{320, 14, 17, 9, 13};
        //creating new labels and adding to list
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            Label l = new Label(String.valueOf(values[i]), UI.createNewLabelStyle(font, Color.WHITE)); //temp label to add
            labels.add(l);
        }

        Image healthIcon = new Image(stat_atlas.findRegion("healthIcon"));
        Image defenseIcon = new Image(stat_atlas.findRegion("defenseIcon"));
        Image attackIcon = new Image(stat_atlas.findRegion("attackIcon"));
        Image magicAttackIcon = new Image(stat_atlas.findRegion("magicAttackIcon"));
        Image magicDefenseIcon = new Image(stat_atlas.findRegion("magicDefenseIcon"));

        table.setDebug(true);
        table.row();
        table.add(healthIcon).height(60f).width(60f);
        table.add(labels.get(0));
        table.row();
        table.add(attackIcon).height(60f).width(60f).right();
        table.add(labels.get(1));
        table.row();
        table.add(defenseIcon).height(60f).width(60f).right();
        table.add(labels.get(2));
        table.row();
        table.add(magicAttackIcon).height(60f).width(60f).right();
        table.add(labels.get(3));
        table.row();
        table.add(magicDefenseIcon).height(60f).width(60f).right();
        table.add(labels.get(4));
        table.row();
```

What I would like is to find a way for the images not to span such a wide area (the red line should just encapsulate the image only and not go beyond it)

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing what you want it to look like. Is the problem that the BACK button is not reaching as far over as the column with the text labels?

Comment: @Tenfour04 i want the symbols at the middle of the table, with the numbers directly beside them

Answer (score 0):

What happened is your back button only takes up one column, so all the labels in the second column have to appear to the right of it. When you add the back button, call `colSpan(2)` on the returned Cell. Also, when you add the labels, you may need to call `left()` on their returned Cells so they push against the images.

This will not necessarily center everything, because of the way Table distributes the extra space of the columns. If you need it all centered, you will actually need an inner table for everything besides your Back button.